# x264 encoding frame rate limit

Tags: c, video, x264

I'm using the following parameters to encode a .mp4 video using the x264 lib:

```
int fps = 30;
x264_param_default_preset(&x.params, "ultrafast", "stillimage,zerolatency");
x.params.i_threads = 1;
x.params.i_fps_num = fps;
x.params.i_fps_den = 1;
x.params.i_timebase_num = 1;
x.params.i_timebase_den = fps;
```

If I set fps to be equal to 25 or less the video encodes in the correct frame rate, however if I try to encode over 25 fps, the frame rate is reduced to 25 fps.

here is a log output, note there are two videos being encoded at the same time:

```
x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
x264 [info]: profile Constrained Baseline, level 4.0
x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
x264 [info]: profile Constrained Baseline, level 4.0
x264 [info]: frame I:2     Avg QP:20.50  size:401756
x264 [info]: frame P:318   Avg QP:24.04  size: 87631
x264 [info]: mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
x264 [info]: mb P  I16..4:  2.5%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 73.3%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:24.2%
x264 [info]: coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 50.6% 59.2% 15.8% inter: 40.1% 21.6% 0.2%
x264 [info]: i16 v,h,dc,p: 14% 34% 40% 12%
x264 [info]: i8c dc,h,v,p: 39% 28% 19% 13%
x264 [info]: kb/s:21502.55
x264 [info]: frame I:2     Avg QP:20.50  size:380898
x264 [info]: frame P:318   Avg QP:24.01  size: 82754
x264 [info]: mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
x264 [info]: mb P  I16..4:  2.5%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 73.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:24.4%
x264 [info]: coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 50.0% 56.0% 14.9% inter: 38.4% 21.8% 0.2%
x264 [info]: i16 v,h,dc,p: 14% 34% 40% 12%
x264 [info]: i8c dc,h,v,p: 39% 29% 19% 13%
x264 [info]: kb/s:20308.27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue myself. Because I was encoding a series of images to the stream, I needed to give avconv a special -framerate option, before all other options, in addition to the regular -r option to specify framerate for encoding.